# Global variable change on dynamic objects

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, get, global

I want to change a global variable to perform a check on the global variable:

As you can see I want the check_short_desc to be a trigger for the operation of the dropdown menu.
This doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var check_short_desc = 0;
    $("#shortdesc").keyup(function () {
        dd_shortdesc = $("#dd_shortdesc");
        $("#dd_shortdesc").css("width", $(this).width());
        thisval = $(this).val().replace("<BR>", "");
        if (thisval.length < 1) {
            $("#dd_shortdesc").fadeOut(180);
        } else {
            $("#dd_shortdesc").fadeIn(180);
        }
        if (check_short_desc == 0) {
            $.get("go_dd.php?action=getsmalldesc&text=" + thisval)
                .done(function (data) {
                    dd_shortdesc.html(data);
                });
        }
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".smalldescli", function () {
        $("#shortdesc").val($(this).text());
        $("#dd_shortdesc").fadeOut();
        check_short_desc = 1;
    });
});
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is expected result? What is result you get?

Comment: Variable stays "0" no matter what.
I want it to change to "1" once the user clicks on ".smalldescli" class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check_short_desc` isn't a global variable in your code. To make it accessible to the click handler, you need to declare it outside of your document.ready function.

Some good information on variable scope in JavaScript can be found here: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/

Comment: oops, but click handler is declared on same scope than check_short_desc, so shouldn't be the issue

Comment: @A.Wolff, you are quite right! When I first looked I thought it wasn't in the same scope. Nir are you sure this solved your problem?

Comment: Well it helped a lot but I was the problem. Everything turned out to be ok and my bad.